# iOS Auto Layout constraints values for different devices sizes

Tags: ios, swift, nslayoutconstraint

I use storyboards for layout my views. I position views with constraints. I have a question about resizing the constraint. How can I set different constraint constants for different devices sizes without programming if/else loops. Is there a way to set it in the storyboard? I have a top constraint to parent layout for example with an constant value of 10. This is okay for the iPhone 5 screen, but on an iPhone 6/ 6 plus screen it should be higher than 10. So the constraint should be calculated. At the moment I calculate an scale factor like this:

```
    let bounds = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds;
    let width = bounds.size.width; 
    let scaleFactor = width/320; // 320 because base design was created for iPhone 5

   // calc top constraint connect from storyboard
  self.topConstraintView.constant = self.topConstraintView.constant * scaleFactor;
```

Is that way correct to deal with constraints on different devices?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you couldn't do it in interface builder? Change the class sizes and set constraints for the classes you want to support.

Comment: How can I set different constraint constants for different device sizes in the interface builder? I don't know how to do this.

Comment: In the interface builder you cannot do it with the same xib, there arent options to implement constraints by changing device type

Comment: okay thanks for help, I thought so. But is there a way to set the constraint relative to margin in the interface builder, so that it scales alone on higher screens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

how about use `DeviceLayout` https://github.com/cruisediary/DeviceLayout

just set constant per device size using `IBInspectable` without any code

[image]

[image]

Comment: I willfully violate the comments rule to say "thanks". This is elegant and concise. Nicely done @cruz.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you can do it with the common **600x600** using class sizes and you can build also an universal (iPad/iPhone) interface. You can find tons of guides to realize it. Depending by what do you want to realize (poor details, more text..) and , one of the possible issue, it's to handle orientation layout correctly (landscape/portrait) because in the big devices many times you must centered your views/objects.

Sometimes it's better, (to dont losing details, image quality..) to realize different xib's based on the different device dimension, especially when you have to do with custom tableViewCells, imageViews.

Here in bottom there are the iPhone different dimensions:

[image]

Comment: thanks very much for the answer. Yes that is the type of storyboard file I use. The size of my view is 600x600. But when I set the top constraint of an ui element to 10, it is 10 on all devices screens. The dimension is fine for iPhone 5, but on iPhones bigger than the iPhone 5 the constant should be higher than 10. I am sorry, but I don't know, how to explain it better :(. Is the only solution here to use different xibs for different devices sizes?

Comment: I know that with size classes you can show/hide elements on different devices, depending on the device size, but what about constraint constants? I want to set different constraint constants on different devices.

Comment: No, using autolayout you can set a top constraint as an IBOutlet called for example topMyViewConstraint and modify it with topMyViewConstraint.constant = 10 + factor checking device type as you request in your question

Comment: About the next comment, simply set all the constraints you want to modify as IBOutlets and you can work with them in your code, but pay attention to the initial values by saving it so you can return back to the original dimensions

Comment: Okay, thank you very much for explaining it. So if I want to change the constraint constant depending on the device screen, I have to do this in code. Is the way I calculate the constant for different devices correct?

Comment: Correct, also when you use autolayout you must always use constraints to make view movements, animations